# Node disconnects the and say: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
register.js:20:18
```

register.js

```
  user.save(function(err) {
    if(err){
      return mainFunctions.sendError(res, req, err, 500, 'error register')
    } else{
      mainFunctions.sendCheck(res, 'Register successful', 200);
      return res.redirect('/');
    }
```

mainFunctions.js

```
module.exports = {
  sendError: function(res, err, status=500, stringLog='withOutStringLog'){
    log.error(stringLog + err);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.status(status).send(JSON.stringify({ err }));
  },
  sendCheck: function(res, stringLog='withOutStringLog', status=200){
    log.info(stringLog);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.status(status).send(JSON.stringify({ stringLog }));
  }
}
```

P.S: And in server.js (main file app), I wrote app.set('json spaces', 0);

Comment: log = winston (logger)

Comment: `user.save` `else` block: you send response with `sendCheck` and then try to send another one (`redirect`).

Comment: FWIW, Express has a useful [`res.json()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) that can save you some code.

Comment: if u call res.send() more than 1 time, it gives this error. you may debug , if this happens

Comment: thx, wostex =)
with 1 res, it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This two lines of code is main problem

```
mainFunctions.sendCheck(res, 'Register successful', 200);
return res.redirect('/');
```

They both try to send response back to client.

In order to fix this. You can just simply comment one of them.

From you code I suggest to you leave `return res.redirect('/');` as it will redirect user on success login/register to main page.

Hope this helps.